# What kind of socket for a 5-position 0.067 pitch part?

Tags: connector, stripboard

What kind of socket would I use to connect a 5-pin 0.067" pitch part (the [Murata OKR-T10-W12](http://power.murata.com/data/power/okr-t10-w12.pdf)) to a piece of normal 0.1" pitch stripboard?

Googling "0.067 5-pin socket" gets me hits for CPU sockets and the like.

Comment: Those aren't usually intended for a socket.

Comment: Try `CAPITAL ADVANCED 33115 SMD ADAPTER, 5-TO-263, 5-SIP` -- adapter board intended for 1.7mm pitch SMT component to 2.54mm (0.100 inch), won't be pretty but might work for this application. The only 1.7mm adapter I found on newark/element14.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams What are they intended for in that case? To be directly soldered onto a board? I wanted to avoid soldering them directly to make them more easily replaceable, and less easily damage-able during the process.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a breakout PCB using Mill-Max female pins and a 0.1" pitch header. Photo (rendering, actually) is from [Digikey](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/0507-0-15-15-31-27-10-0/ED1338-ND/4879976), Mill-Max 0507-0-15-15-31-27-10-0.

[image]

Or if you're in a hurry, just solder some bare extension wires on and stick them in the breadboard (staggered).

Comment: Soldering the pins bare was something I was trying to avoid, as above.